# Variant pronunciation of "obesity"

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

A question mainly for Americans:

Could you please confirm if some Americans indeed pronounce the "e" of "obesity" as the "ea" of "steady" rather than the "ee" of "bee" (o-be-si-ty instead of o-bee-si-ty? Merriam-Webster lists it as a variant pronunciation, yet, i haven't heard any American say the word this way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obesity) only shows the standard pronunciation. Which edition do you have? How old is it?

Comment: I've subscribed to the unabridged version. Here's the entry: obe·si·ty noun \ōˈbēsətē, -bes-, -ətē, -i\...but I haven't heard anyone use the second variant. How would you pronounce it?

Comment: He's just “taking the piss out of“ Americans?  : ) (No - never heard that pronunciation before.)

Comment: Appears to be nothing under after the "Here it is" but I've never heard a pronunciation of it that sounds like what you describe.

Comment: On the other hand, the [1892 Webster's International](http://books.google.com/books?id=qL8WAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=webster+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VkbuUof9NajSsATCq4D4Bw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=ode&f=false) only shows the "incorrect" pronunciation. I think is a case where the pronunciation has changed over time, and the dictionary has not yet dropped the old one.

Comment: Hi Peter, their online unabridged dictionary (paid one) shows both. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The OED says of that word’s  pronunciation:

> **obesity** /əʊˈbiːsɪtɪ/, *older* /-ˈbɛsɪtɪ/.

That says it used to be pronounced with an /ɛ/ instead of the /i/ that is universally heard today.

Also, the first vowel in General American is more likely to be [oʊ] than the RP [əʊ] vowel which does not occur in GA. However, since it is not stressed, it is subject to typical reduction patterns, which can lead to [o], [ɒ], [ɵ], or [ə] in rapid or relaxed speech.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's interesting that many Filipinos stick to the older pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an American and have been for all my life, yet have never heard anyone pronounce it as "obesity" (not "obeesity"). I've always pronounced it as the latter, and everyone I know does. The Merriam-Webster online dictionary also states it as its pronunciation. ':)