# vowel sound in "stair" pronounced similarly as the "eɪ" diphthong in "fake"?

Tags: pronunciation

Sometimes in words which have the ɛ sound followed by an "r"  as in "stair", "their" "bear", "where" I hear them pronounced like "steɪəɹ", ðeɪəɹ etc. with the "eɪ" as in "fake", "lake","make" and not with the ɛ as in "bed","fed", "let".

Do I hear it right?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Presumably, you're talking about American English because you put an /ɹ/ in. In General American English, /eɪ/ and /ɛ/ have merged before /r/, so *fairy* and *ferry* are pronounced the same. Some Americans pronounce *bear* with /eɪ/ and some with /ɛ/. But I believe *bearing* is usually pronounced with /ɛ/.

Comment: I'm American, and I don't pronounce fairy and ferry the same way.

Comment: I've never heard *stair* (or *stare*) pronounced to rhyme with *they're*, or the common British pronunciation of *mayor*, if that is what the OP is asking.

Comment: Me neither, but I could not think of an other IPA symbol to discribe how it sounds to me. It is like that in the case of "stair" the /eɪ/ lacks the "j" sound.

Comment: @Steven Littman: Two-thirds of Americans pronounce them the same. [Reference](https://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/q_15.html). But I definitely don't want to imply you're pronouncing them wrong; there are lots of American dialects that still have this distinction.

Comment: And it's a distinction worth keeping.  They are three words with three distinct meanings, and all of the vowel sounds that I use to distinguish Mary, marry and merry exist in English (as opposed to, let's say, the sound of u in deja vu (pronounced as it is in French).  And it would be silly to say that John would marry Mary, but he wouldn't marry Merry, and have them sound like he would Mary Mary but he wouldn't Mary Mary.

Comment: Could you tell me what's the difference between their pronouciation, please?

Comment: The difference is covered in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88115/how-are-marry-merry-and-mary-pronounced-differently), although listening to the pronunciations in a British dictionary might help (unless you want the differences in an American dialect).

Comment: @Steven: I've never had any problem with confusing *merry, marry* and *Mary*; they can almost always be disambiguated by context. *Aaron* and *Erin*, on the other hand ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't specify the accent/dialect in question.